# initial-letter doesn't show the correct font

Tags: css, fonts, epub, ibooks, calibre

I'm creating an ebook with calibre but I can't set a good drop cap because the letter doesn't follow the ***font-family*** rule in the css.

Here's my code:

```
p:first-of-type:first-letter {
    font-family: "Dearest" !important;
    initial-letter: 3;
    -webkit-initial-letter: 3;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
    color: #903;
}
```

The drop cap works only with the font specified in ***p { }***
(I tested the ebook on iBooks for Mac)
How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Which version of Calibre? And directly related to that, which version of CSS does that support? (`first-letter` has been in CSS since CSS1, but `first-of-type` is a CSS3 feature).

Comment: Can you confirm that the rest of the style (such as the color) _does_ work? So it's not the selector that is the problem? In that case, I'd check if the "Dearest" font displays at all. Is it a webfont?

Comment: first-of-type works and the color works too but the letter is not displayed as a dropcap